# Static Context: Is it worth it?

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks, android-context

I have this code in my Application class:

```
public class MyApp extends MultiDexApplication {
 
    private static Application context;
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        context = this;  
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base); 
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return context.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

When I want to access the context I use this code:

```
Context context = MyApp.getAppContext();
```

I have read multiple times that accessing Context in a static way has it's downsides like memory leaking. I am about to publish a huge app I have been working on the last years and I wonder if I should change my current approach.

So far I haven't faced any problems with memory leaking but I haven't test my app in multiple devices or generally in mass production.

Is there anyone who has used this approach in his published app and found out that there is nothing wrong with this code?

Comment: this doesn't have anything to do with android studio, right ? just using the IDE doesn't mean you have to add the tag for it, the tag is only there when asking about a feature of the IDE itself

Comment: i don't really see a need for using context like this to be honest, often it just feels like a lazy approach to having context available when/where you need it and often it is already available to you, but there are lots of posts and questions about this already

Comment: I know it's a lazy approach. Although time management is important and if you are dealing with a project bigger than 200.000 lines of code, you need to minimize everything.

Comment: `time management is important` this has nothing to do with time management. using `MyApp.getAppContext()` or using `requireContext()` or the equivalent method for getting context when and where you need it makes very little of a difference. if you're going to spend days/hours getting context where you need it, chances are you need to review the basics more, because getting context should be the least of your worries

Comment: It kind of does actually. It's not just the point where you request the context variable, it's also about passing the variable from method to method. The code looks much cleaner when I just get the context using MyApp.getAppContext().

Comment: your code might look cleaner, but by hiding away dependencies like this, you're making it harder to unit test your code, so you gain one thing and lost something else, having `private static Application context;` is definitely up for debate whether or not this is actually clean code. but again, this is a pointless discussion, and what you're asking already has tons of articles and posts on, so if you're not having memory leaks using this approach, which you probably won't be having, then go for it

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the issue with context ref in static class is mainly with Activity or Fragment classes.
Activities can live and die, and you don't know if the Context is still valid.
When using Application Context you can be pretty sure that the ref is valid and the App is alive, when executing code within the application.